# New-SPContentDatabase vs Mount-SPContentDatabase

Tags: content-database, best-practices

We pre-create our SharePoint content databases in SQL, so we can distribute database files among disks and tune some parameters on the SQL Server side. Then we convert the SQL databases into SharePoint content databases by issuing a **New-SPContentDatabase** from a web front end, specifying the name of the existing, newly created SQL database. According to our experience, the cmdlet will not create a database but reuse the existing one, and will proceed to create the SharePoint schema into it. However, I've found no documentation regarding this behavior.

According to documentation, **Mount-SPContentDatabase** does more or less the same thing, given that the database exists already, which is the case in our context.

The question is, are there any relevant difference between using **New-SPContentDatabase** and **Mount-SPContentDatabase** when the target database already exists, and is empty?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

The **New-SPContentDatabase** cmdlet creates a new content database and attaches it to the specified Web application.

The **Mount-SPContentDatabase** cmdlet attaches an existing content database to the farm. If the database being mounted requires an upgrade, this cmdlet will cause the database to be upgraded.

so if you created database in advance, make sure the collation should be as per SharePoint requirement. then you need to mount the db to web application.

here is the blog explain more:
http://blog.octavie.nl/index.php/2013/05/29/pre-creating-content-databases-or-not/

Comment: Yes, that's what the documentation says, but the fact is that **New-SPContentDatabase** will not create the database if already exists another database in the farm instance. So, as this is the case, at first sight both cmdlets would do the same.

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer to my question, maybe it helps someone. Credits for this answer go to [SharePoint MC](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/profile/sharepointmc/?type=forum&referrer=http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/99c81342-d085-4226-87d4-e0ea4447b6b6/newspcontentdatabase-or-mountspcontentdatabase?forum=sharepointadminprevious), who kindly answered to my question on MS Forums:

**Create-SPContentDatabase** is the base class for **Mount-SPContentDatabase**.

The additions to the **Mount-SPContentDatabase** are switches for **UpdateUserExperience**, and **SkipIntegrityChecks**.

It calls the base **Create-SPContentDatabase** for anything else, and only overrides the internal validation in order to set the private fields in the **Create-SPContentDatabase** that equate to those two switches... so those switches are just set by default in the **Create-SPContentDatabase**, and **Mount** just gives you the ability to override those...